# NumPy calculate square of norm 2 of vector

Tags: python, numpy, inner-product

I have vector `a`.
I want to calculate `np.inner(a, a)`
But I wonder whether there is prettier way to calc it.

[The disadvantage of this way, that if I want to calculate it for `a-b` or a bit more complex expression, I have to do that with one more line. `c = a - b` and `np.inner(c, c)` instead of `somewhat(a - b)`]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Honestly there's probably not going to be anything faster than `np.inner` or `np.dot`. If you find intermediate variables annoying, you could always create a lambda function:

```
sqeuclidean = lambda x: np.inner(x, x)
```

`np.inner` and `np.dot` leverage BLAS routines, and will almost certainly be faster than standard elementwise multiplication followed by summation.

```
In [1]: %%timeit -n 1 -r 100 a, b = np.random.randn(2, 1000000)
((a - b) ** 2).sum()
   ....: 
The slowest run took 36.13 times longer than the fastest. This could mean that an intermediate result is being cached 
1 loops, best of 100: 6.45 ms per loop

In [2]: %%timeit -n 1 -r 100 a, b = np.random.randn(2, 1000000)                                                                                                                                                                              
np.linalg.norm(a - b, ord=2) ** 2
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 100: 2.74 ms per loop

In [3]: %%timeit -n 1 -r 100 a, b = np.random.randn(2, 1000000)
sqeuclidean(a - b)
   ....: 
1 loops, best of 100: 2.64 ms per loop
```

`np.linalg.norm(..., ord=2)` uses `np.dot` internally, and gives very similar performance to using `np.inner` directly.

Comment: I think that the result is cached (as warned for!) and this is incorrect. I find that that `(x**2).sum()` is about 6 times faster than the other two methods. So this answer recommends using a much slower method.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if the performance is any good, but `(a**2).sum()` calculates the right value and has the non-repeated argument you want. You can replace `a` with some complicated expression without binding it to a variable, just remember to use parentheses as necessary, since `**` binds more tightly than most other operators: `((a-b)**2).sum()`

Comment: I thought that obviously there is dedicated way to do it, but it seems it's the best way.

Answer (score 5):

to calculate norm2

```
numpy.linalg.norm(x, ord=2)
```

`numpy.linalg.norm(x, ord=2)**2` for square

Comment: I know that solution, but it has runtime price.

Comment: Did you tested it? @Dubon

Comment: No, but why to do square root if you square it after that?

Comment: @Dubon The square root and the subsequent square are performed on a single float rather than an n-long vector - they contribute a trivial amount to the total runtime

Comment: The argument `ord=2` is unnecessary as the Frobenius norm is used by default.

Answer (score 2):

In case you end up here looking for a fast way to get the squared norm, these are some tests showing `distances = np.sum((descriptors - desc[None])**2, axis=1)` to be the quickest.

```py
import timeit

setup_code = """
import numpy as np
descriptors = np.random.rand(3000, 512)
desc = np.random.rand(512)
"""

norm_code = """
np.linalg.norm(descriptors - desc[None], axis=-1)
"""
norm_time = timeit.timeit(stmt=norm_code, setup=setup_code, number=100, )

einsum_code = """
x = descriptors - desc[None]
sqrd_dist = np.einsum('ij,ij -> i', x, x)
"""
einsum_time = timeit.timeit(stmt=einsum_code, setup=setup_code, number=100, )

norm_sqrd_code = """
distances = np.sum((descriptors - desc[None])**2, axis=1)
"""
norm_sqrd_time = timeit.timeit(stmt=norm_sqrd_code, setup=setup_code, number=100, )

print(norm_time) # 0.7688689678907394
print(einsum_time) # 0.29194538854062557
print(norm_sqrd_time) # 0.274090813472867
```